# What is a Class-B crime and its punishment in Superman?

Tags: dc, superman, dc-extended-universe, man-of-steel

In *Man of Steel*, Jor-El goes to the Genesis chamber and steals the codex. Before he goes in, Kelex states,

> **Jor-EL:** Can you see the codex?
>
> **Kelex:** Its just beneath the central hub sir. But I am compelled to warn you, breaching the Genesis chamber is a Class-B crime punishable
> by.......

But, Kelex is cut short by Jor-EL as he says "that nobody cares any more."

1. Is there any canon information in the comics, screen play/movie or books
   that states what a Class-B's punishment is?
2. And if there is, are there any other crimes listed and their punishment?

*And I guess including Genral Zod's punishment for treason and murder is relevant as well for the second point.*

Comment: It’s actually not a B, it’s the Kryptonian symbol representing weary frustration with a convoluted penal code.